# Input type "file" returns EMPTY in Laravel php

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I have this problem getting my string to an input type file, I'd try changing the input type to text, and when I return $request it works (just with type text, with file type it returns empty).
I'd put enctype="multipart/form-data" but that still empty value for file input.

web.php

```
    Route::get('/profile', 'miPerfilController@index')->name('profile');

    Route::post('/profile/update', 'miPerfilController@updatePhoto')->name('profile.update');
```

updatePhoto.blade.php

```
<form class="form-group" method="POST" action="/profile/update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="modal fade row" id="updatePhoto">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="mb-5 form-group" >
                        <h3 class="pull-left">Update profile image</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span>
                                &times;
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <label v-for="error in errors" class="text-danger">@{{ error }}</label>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Choose image<span class="help"></span></label>
                        <br><br>
                        <input type="file" name="profile_image" id="profile_image"
                               class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

miPerfilController.php

```
public function updatePhoto( Request $request )
    {
        return $request;
    }
```

Result

[image: EMPTY profile_image value]

Comment: what's your file size?? try to check `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` file or try with a smaller file to check if it works.

Answer (score 3):

**write the form tag like this**

```
<form class="form-group" method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.update') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: It`s the same problem, it returns empty.

Comment: Please select this answer if you help this answer thank you .

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
 public function updatePhoto( Request $request , $id )
        {
            return $request->all();
        }
```

Comment: beacuse you not pass in type hinting in id so pass id in your function.

Comment: Please select this answer if you help this answer thank you .

Answer (score 1):

**You should try to get files using `$request->file()` method.**

```
 public function updatePhoto( Request $request , $id ){

    if ($request->file('profile_image')) {

      print_r($request->file('profile_image'));

    } else {

      echo 'file not found';
    }
 }
```

Thanks.